# Do report subscriptions contribute to email limits?

Tags: lightning, email, reporting, governorlimits, subscriber

So I have a group of users (around 20 users at least) for which I wish to subscribe the reports as a System Administrator in lightning experience. It is required that only the admin can subscribe and add the users in the list of recipients. These reports have to be scheduled on a daily basis and may show around 200-300 records. I wanted to understand if this would add to the  email limits set up for my org or the report subscription mails have a separate limit. Unable to find any clear documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems report subscriptions have their own limits that are separate from the email limits Salesforce imposes.

[Report Limits, Limitations, and Allocations reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rd_reports_dashboards_limits.htm&type=5)

Some important notes:

- Users are limited to subscribing to only 5 reports. There's this [idea to increase the limit](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DkodAAC) with a recent comment about this being a high priority to change in the next 2-3 releases.
- Reports display a maximum of 2,000 rows
- You can have 200 scheduled reports (even those scheduled with no future runs count towards this)

[image]